# React native init project issue in macos

Tags: react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

i was trying to create a new react native project but i was showing ruby gems not installed we tried using `sudo gem install` but it gave error folder permission required

```
                  Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Ruby Gems

error /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:264:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

✖ Installing Ruby Gems

error Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos&platform=android and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to project root directory

> cd ios && pod install --repo-update

> react-native run-ios

this will solve the pod issue for you in ios